# App suited to saving math articles for offline reading?

Tags: discussion

Not sure if this belongs on the main site.

I sometimes like to save articles on my tablet for offline reading later since one never knows when internet connection may be spotty. I use the app Pocket to save articles from places like the New York Times, ESPN, etc. but it does not work well with math articles or math blog posts, since it doesn't support LaTeX.

Does anyone know if there are any apps to save mathematics articles for offline reading which support LaTeX?

Comment: MSE uses MathJax to render the TeX. If you want to save the source of a page, you could render it on your own as long as you had a local copy of MathJax (which you can get pretty easily) *and* you pointed your local page to your MathJax installation. I don't know of any app that does this automatically. Presumably, one could somehow integrate saved pages into a local TeX installation. An alternative would be to save rendered pages as (for example) pdfs or djvus, which is possible. These aren't particularly user friendly, though.

Comment: In the spirit of one of the alternative proposed by @mixedmath, you might be interested by this topic: [Save the answer in PDF?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15163/save-the-answer-in-pdf)